# when is onSizeChanged() called?

Tags: android

Is `onSizeChanged()` called once the user touches some part of the screen?

I'm confused about the order in which `onDraw()`, `onMeasure()` and `onSizeChanged()` are called.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Android doesn't know the real size at start, it needs to calculate it. Once it's done, `onSizeChanged()` will notify you with the real size.

`onSizeChanged()` is called once the size as been calculated. Events don't have to come from users all the time. In this example when android change the size, `onSizeChanged()` is called. Same thing with `onDraw()`, when the view should be drawn `onDraw()` is called.

`onMeasure()` is called automatically right after a call to `measure()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you give me an example of an instance when the size changes?

Comment: I updated the solution. The main call to onSizeChanged() is done after the construction of your view but before the drawing. At this time the system will calculate the size of your view and notify you by calling `onSizeChanged()`

Comment: This is much better than the ViewTreeObserver alternative.

Comment: `onSizeChanged()` is (at least sometimes) called from within `layout()`. In that case it's usually called before any `OnLayoutChangeListener`s.