# android get drawable area in onCreate method

Tags: android, layout, dimensions

if I have a layout with fill_parent at height and width, is there a way to get his height and width in onCreate method? if not, when his dimensions are available? I need this because I need to add at runtime some views and I need to know how many views fill in the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that:.
Suppose you have the layout view in onCreate method

```
     layout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
          public void run() {
            height= getHeight();
            width=getWidth();        
            //pupulate other views now that you know the parent size     
            }
        }
  });
```

Comment: I thought at this solution, but when will be this runnable executed? if it will be executed before all views are drawn? and if it will be executed after all views are drawn, it's not a simple solution to notify a object so I can use this values... it must be a simple way...

Comment: Accepted my answer but at your comments you seem you didn't find the solution. Was that a missclick and want more help or that works?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onSizeChanged` method to get the information when it has been calculated, but this may also help to at least get the dimensions of the display.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
```

You may find this useful:

[when is onSizeChanged() called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526148/when-is-onsizechanged-called)

Comment: onSizeChanged is a view method. I need to add ImageView to my screen, I don't make costum layout. and display will give you the full height of the screen. I need only drawable area, on title bar and on notification area you can not draw views

Comment: fill_parent doesn't always mean the whole screen. In fact almost never since you have the notification bar.

Comment: @weakwire - You can get an idea as to the size to calculate how many views to place based on the size of the display, as with rounding the notification bar can be ignored.

Comment: @gabi - Depending on how perfect you need getting the size of the display and then doing this in onCreate should be sufficient. You will also have a problem if you allow it to switch to landscape/portrait modes as the viewable area will change.