# Android Composite View Initialization

Tags: android

I'm writing a composite view by overriding a `ViewGroup`, like so:

```
public class CompositeView extends RelativeLayout
```

I need to perform some one-time initialization after the measurements have been set (i.e. onMeasure has been called) because I need to know the height.

I was thinking of overriding [onAttachedToWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29), but the docs mention that:

> it may be called any time before the first onDraw -- including before or after onMeasure(int, int).

What other options do I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use onSizeChanged in my CustomViews:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh) {
    boolean changed = false;
    changed |= w != oldw;
    changed |= h != oldh;
    changed &= w > 0;
    changed &= h > 0;
    if (changed) {
            //do initialization stuff here
            ...
```

This method is called once after layouting is finished. This [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526148/when-is-onsizechanged-called) gives some extra details.

Comment: This is guaranteed to be called once?

Comment: its called once as soon as the size of the view is determined. I edited my anser to reflect that

Comment: Thanks. I never knew bitwise operators could be applied to booleans.  Learned something else new.

Comment: please note that in case of boolean these operators are not bitwise operators but logical ones instead.